# SQLite + EntityFramework pair leaves the connection alive after disposing of the context

Tags: c#, entity-framework, system.data.sqlite

I'm using SQLite for .Net and EntityFramework from .Net Framework 4.0. Everything was ok until I moved from SQLite v.1.0.79.0 to v.1.0.86.0. From that time code like this

```
using (var context = new EntityContent(sqliteConnectionString))
{
    context.ExecuteStoreCommand(mySqlScriptString);
    /*
     * or do some stuff with context entities and call context.SaveChanges()
     */
}
deleteSQLiteDbFile(getDbFilePath(sqliteConnectionString)); // <-- here is the error
```

throws the error System.IO.IOException: "The process cannot access the file 'mydatabase.dat' because it is being used by another process."

It's all because of moving to the new sqlite3_close_v2() API in SQLite v.1.0.82.0 (see [this](http://sqlite.1065341.n5.nabble.com/Change-in-behavior-between-1-0-79-0-and-1-0-83-0-in-System-Data-SQLite-td66402.html)). As you can see in [this ticket](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/info/3186bfc523) you should properly dispose all sqlite commands and readers. But EF 4 doesn't do it (at least in the .net framework 4 version). For instance, see `ObjectContent.ExecuteStoreCommand` method. It implicitly creates a command from SQLite connection and doesn't dispose it.

Yes, I can write my own `executeStoreCommand(ObjectContent context, string script, params object[] parameters)` method with proper command disposing but what to do with `context.SaveChanges()`?

Does anybody know if it fixed in next releases of EF or SQLite? Or may be there are any workarounds?

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this problem is a changed close behavior in the System.Data.SQLite which is somehow not compatible with EF anymore.
Details see here: http://www.mail-archive.com/sqlite-users%40sqlite.org/msg74770.html

Since this was only in my integration tests I used the workaround from here to solve that:
[System.Data.SQLite Close() not releasing database file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8511901/system-data-sqlite-close-not-releasing-database-file)