# Close connection in SQLite-WinRT wrapper

Tags: c#, windows, sqlite, windows-runtime, windows-8.1

How to close all database connections in [SQLite-WinRT wrapper](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/andy_wigley/2013/11/21/how-to-massively-improve-sqlite-performance-using-sqlwinrt/). I need to delete the sqlite database but it is throwing exception `Access is denied` while deleting since some connection is already using database. So I need to close all the connections before deleting.

I have tried disposing database like:

```
var dbFile = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(dbPath);
db = new SQLiteWinRT.Database(dbFile); 
db.Dispose();
```

But it doesn't work and throws the same exception.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes SQLite doesn't dispose correctly. To get around this you can call `Collect` on the garbage collector.

**Example**

```
var dbFile = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(dbPath);
db = new SQLiteWinRT.Database(dbFile); 
db.Dispose();

// Then force GC
GC.Collect();
```

If this doesn't work for you see this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8511901/1593273) for some alternative solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Perform your DB oriented operations within `using {...}` block.

> The using statement obtains one or more resources, executes a statement, and then disposes of the resource.

Example:

```
using (var db = new SQLiteConnection(DbPath))
{
    db.Trace = true;
    db.Execute("DELETE FROM Person WHERE Id = ?", person.Id);
}
```

Comment: Hi M. Hassan, Thanks for your answer. There are lot of DB operations in different parts and passing the DbPath as parameter and creating new instance every time within `using{ . . .}` block doesn't seem to be feasible to me. Are there any options you can think of?

Comment: Was afraid of that case. You'd need to make changes one way or other. Connection pooling might help.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. In my case I had not disposed of prepared statements correctly. Every time you call `PrepareStatementAsync` you have to call `Dispose` on the resulting statement (or use `using`).