# How to move/delete sqlite file after opening an sqliteConnection

Tags: vb.net, sqlite

I want the user to be able to move the sqlite file after the program already opened a connection with it:

```
Dim conn As New SQLite.SQLiteConnection()

conn.ConnectionString = connString

conn.Open()
```

But of course the program can't do that because file is being used by an other process. Closing the connection, calling `conn.Dispose()`, doesn't release the file.

So how can i release the file so then i can move it to an other location?

Comment: The code you have above has nothing to do with `moving a file`. I would assume the file is being accessed by the `SqliteConnection` class and locks this down, obviously locking access to it. ***but....*** it matters how you are **opening & closing/disposing** these objects as well; I have a good feeling your not cleaning up your objects. Could you please show us how you are making your connections and calls?

Comment: Paying atention to what you said, i found out that i also needed to dispose the `SQLiteCommand` connection. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome, wrap those in `Using` statements... This ensures they get disposed.

Answer (score -1):

Even after calling Dispose, there's a pointer internally that isn't released until the CLR's garbage collector runs. The file can't be moved until that happens. To force it, just run GC.Collect() after the Dispose.

Comment: Detailed in this older post, but still very much true: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8511901/system-data-sqlite-close-not-releasing-database-file