# Releasing a Database in Sqlite

Tags: c++, sqlite

I'm having trouble deleting a file using C++ 'remove' in my sqlite project.   All I'm trying to do is delete a database file.  The problem is it won't delete.

I found the below solution which says that you just call query.close() to release the database file in sqlite but I'm just not sure how to do that?  I have never used a query class in sqlite. Does anyone know how to call the query.clear() method?

Here's the link to the solution to the same problem I have - 
[Releasing the Database in sqlite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8511901/system-data-sqlite-close-not-releasing-database-file).

The other links to this never solve the issue.. They talk about garbage collection but don't explain how this is done.

Comment: What is 'remove'? Show code. Your link does not refer to C++.

Comment: `close` is a method of the connection, not of the query.

Comment: Put another way.  How do you execute the query.clear() method shown in the above linke?  Let's forget about the C++ remove method for now.

Comment: Which kind of Sqlite interface are you using? The C++ interface provides sqlite3_open() and sqlite3_close() methods to open and close db connection.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [System.Data.SQLite Close() not releasing database file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8511901/system-data-sqlite-close-not-releasing-database-file)

Comment: sqlite_close doesn't close the connection.. It just de-allocates it from what I understand.  The query has to be deleted as well.  This is where I'm getting stuck.  If I try to delete the Database file in my program, it won't delete because it is 'Busy'.  It is 'Busy' despite calling sqlite_close.  I'm using sqlite3.  I've also tried using sqlite3_close_v2 with no luck either.